# Issue with Embedded Coder Target for Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino, embedded, simulink, arduino-uno

I am following this [MathWorks File Exchange Link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30277-embedded-coder-target-for-arduino). I am having problem while running the `myarduino_blink.slx` demo.

My MATLAB version is R2015a, and I am using an Arduino Uno. I ran the file `setup_custom_target_arduino.m` after changing the relevant directory listing and the arduino version in the m file, and I got the output of Arduino on COM 3, which was correct.

After this, I checked the Simulink Library Browser and I had the Custom C/C++ Target Arduino Library will all its modules. Now when I simulate the model, I get the following error:

> Error in S-function 'myarduino_blink/Digital Output':
>   S-Function 'sfunar_digitalOutput' does not exist

Kindly help me out, what could I have done wrong?

**Update 1**

Ok, I solved the "does not exist" problem. Apparently, no MEX compiler was installed. So I installed the Windows SDK, then re-ran the m file and now I am able to generate the .mex64 files. Now I run into another problem, when I build the simulink model, it gives this error:

> #### Build procedure for model: 'myarduino_blink' aborted due to an error

How to solve this?

Comment: Please add more information.

Answer (score 1):

`setup_custom_target_arduino.m` calls `build_all_sfunctions.m` which should compile all of the S-Functions in the `blocks` directory.  It looks as if that hasn't occurred for some reason.  Check in the `blocks` directory that each of the S-Functions has a `.c`, `.tlc` (both of which come with the package) and a `.mex64` (which is the compiled version of the `.c` generated by `build_all_sfunctions.m`) file.

If they are not there then the setup hasn't executed correctly, and you'll need to compile all of the S-Functions.
If they are there then you most likely have some sort of path issue (although since you say you can see the library in the library browser this seems unlikely).

Comment: Thanks, solved a part of the problem, now I ran into another one, mentioned in the update to the question.

Comment: You're going to have to give us more than that very generic, and next to useless error message.  Are you sure there isn't a second part to the message giving more specific information?